# How to write if statement with *args?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

if anyone can guide me how to write the below statement, I want to check if x value is greater than 10 then only it's print it out

```
def __num__(*args):
    if x > 10 in args:
        print('I am testing args using {}'.format(__num__[x]))
    else :
        print('Something Goes Wrong')   

__num__(x = 22)
```

Comment: I think you mean `**kwargs`? And then you can do in the function `if kwargs[x] > 10`

Comment: If your function only exists to check an x parameter, why doesn’t it just take an x parameter? What would ˋ__num__(y=12)ˋ do?

Answer (score 1):

If you know all the arguments are numbers, an easy way is a little comprehension.

```
def __num__(*args):
    if any([arg for arg in args if arg > 10]):
        print('I am testing args using {}'.format(args['x']))
    else :
        print('Something Goes Wrong')
```

If you're going to get non-numerics, you'll have to check each arg to see if its a number. That's just a small change to the previous list-comp.

```
import numbers

def __num__(*args):
     if any([arg for arg in args if isinstance(arg, numbers.Number) and arg > 10]):
        print('I am testing args using {}'.format(args['x']))
    else :
        print('Something Goes Wrong')
```

As others have said, it would probably be easier to have a dedicated argument just for this